# what happens when unpackWAR is set to false in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am looking for a way to run the same Java application on multiple VMs which access the same war file (shared storage). Sometimes, the deployment fails due to file locking issues. I thought of doing this:
- set unpackWAR=false
- extract the war file manually using a script
The performance has now degraded a lot. It seems like, tomcat is using the war file only and not the extracted content. So, I am looking for information on how this works. Is there a way to explicitly point out to Tomcat to use the extracted war content (assuming it doesn't, if unpackWAR is set to false)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to save, when you already have different VMs - it can't be heavier than that. IMHO you should be able to invest in the bit of storage to have their own webapps directory, with their private copy of the application.

If you declare `unpackWAR=false` you don't need to manually unzip: It won't make a difference. You've told Tomcat to not bother unpacking and it most likely won't look at an unpacked directory once it found its WAR application.

*If* you really want to share, you should omit the war file and share the full application, but if you're running into locking issues: Just don't share.

Comment: - The war has to be shared (that's something by design which cannot be changed)
- Yes, unpackWAR=false doesn't need us to manually unzip the war. However, I have to do it where of some other dependency. 
- I don't know if Tomcat is using the extracted content in this scenario. If not, I want it to use the extracted one.

Comment: Then don't specify unpackWAR=true, and copy the exploded war file directly to the target destination. If question the design imperative though